# Start and Stop function apps in Powershell

Tags: azure-devops, azure-functions

I have stop and restart the Azure function app as part of my release process. I imported AzurePowerShell and using Inline Script.

```
enter code here
Stop-AzFunctionApp -Name fn-x-us-ed-HR02 -ResourceGroupName rg-t-HR02
```

getting below error.

The term 'Stop-AzFunctionApp' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.

I tried 'Stop-AzureRmWebApp' and getting same error.

I have 4 function apps and want to stop before deploying new and then restart.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be missing the latest Az.Functions module. Make sure you import v1.0.0 from the PowerShell Gallery: https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/Az.Functions/1.0.0

Comment: Thanks. I am running this from the release pipeline deployment steps. How Can I get all the azure functions app in particular resource group?

Comment: @Andrew Something like this: `Get-AzResource -ResourceGroupName 'MyRGName' -ResourceType 'Microsoft.Web/sites' -ExpandProperties | ?{ $_.Properties.kind -eq 'functionapp' }`. This is an entirely separate question though :-)